# Invisible overlaying DIV blocking hover? + positioning

Tags: html, css, positioning, conflict

I will start with saying that I'm not terribly experienced, so I'm sure my code is not very "clean" :-)

The page I am talking about can be viewed here:

http://www.fordesignpurposes.com/so/00menu.html

CSS link:

http://www.fordesignpurposes.com/so/style.css

Anyway: I am trying to build a responsive menu which consists of several image-buttons which change upon hover. However, I've discovered that the hover/link will only occur when hovering over the top 30% of the buttons. Hovering on the button below that threshold, it goes dead.

There is a media query to separate the buttons on two rows once the screen becomes too small, but interestingly enough both rows then still exhibit the same problem (instead of only the top 30% of the top row working, for instance).

From searching similar SO questions I am suspecting there is a conflict with an overlaying div, but for the life of me I cannot figure out where the problem lies. Can anyone help me with this?

Another question is probably really simple, but I can't seem to figure that out either. As I mentioned above, on smaller screen the menu changes to two rows. I would like to move the bottom row closer to the top, but I can't make it happen. What is the correct combination of positioning I should be using in elements for this?

I hope I'm not asking too much!

Comment: it works fine for me in Firefox, which browser are you using to test?

Comment: the problem is because of the line-height currently the line-height of the links is 0 increase the line-height to 18px which will increase the space between the two nav rows and about your second question you can decrease the height of the by 2px because margin-top:2px is given to #buttonsB in @ media (max-width:550px)

Comment: I tried Safari and Chrome, both latest versions. But you are right, I just tried firefox and the issue seems to disappear? Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Height of your images are 0px currently thats why hovering only works on top of the image.(not even 30 percent).
You should set height or change your line-height property (set to non-zero value for ex: 20px in your case)

I took another look and saw your anchors are floated. try to clear your floats. that should work too

Comment: Thanks a lot! The thing is, the buttons do not have a fixed height, since they after a certain width threshold become smaller to fit the screen. How do I deal with that?

Comment: for ex: dimensions of your button1_01.png file is 119X15. give same width and height by using css too. your widths are currently percentage. dont use max-width or percentages for your images

Comment: Thanks a lot! In the end I was able to solve the problemn by setting a line height and using a negative top margin for the bottom row to close the gap between the two. So, great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add: line-height: 12px style to your #buttons selector in the CSS file:

```
#buttons 
{ 
  line-height: 12px;
}
```

right now, they're set at 0px. Change it and it should work!